# from Firebase database retrieve details against a particular value using angular

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database

In my demo application I have an 'Employee' interface which contains the below fields:
**employee.ts**

```
export interface Employee{
    id:string;
    firstName:string;
    lastName:string;
    email:string;
    mobileNumber:string;

}
```

In the UI I am showing all the employee added in Firebase database.
Now ,with the employee Id I want to update that employee's particular data.
**edit-employee.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../employee';
import { EmployeeService } from '../employee.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-employee',
  templateUrl: './edit-employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-employee.component.css']
})
export class EditEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
employee:Employee;
id:string;
submitted:boolean=false;
  constructor(private employeeService:EmployeeService,
    private activeRoute:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(
    (data)=>{
       this.id=data['id'] 
    }
    );
    console.log('id::'+this.id);
    this.employeeService.getEmployeeById(this.id).subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        this.employee=data.map((e)=>{
            return{
              firstName:e.payload.doc.data()['firstName'],
              lastName: e.payload.doc.data()['lastName']
            }
        })
        console.log(this.employee);
      }
    )
  }
  onSubmit(){
    console.log('submitted');
    this.submitted=true;
  }

}
```

**employee.service.ts:**

```
getEmployeeById(id:string):Observable<any>{
   //return this.firestore.collection('users').doc(id).valueChanges();
   return this.firestore.doc('users/'+id).get();
  }
```

I want to populate data against employee id selected from the UI.
But I am getting an error to populate those data.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the type of data in console.log(data); ? .. 
For sure, it's not an array, for which the data.map() is failing.

Comment: do I need to change anything in the service class for getEmployeeById() method. getEmployeeById(id:string):Observable<any>{
   //return this.firestore.collection('users').doc(id).valueChanges();
   return this.firestore.doc('users/'+id).snapshotChanges();
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering id is the Document ID of the object stored in Firestore. This will return an object.

```
return this.firestore.doc('users/'+id).valueChanges();
```

Else, if it's an attribute of the saved object, then you have to query in the collection. This will return an array of objects. Only 1, if the id is unique

```
return this.firestore.collection('users', ref => ref.where('id', '==', id)).valueChanges();
```

Log this data in the subscribe. It should be the exact object that you might have saved in the firestore.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(
    (data)=>{
      this.id = data['id'] 
      console.log('id::'+this.id);
      this.employeeService.getEmployeeById(this.id).subscribe(
       (data)=>{
         console.log(data); // Should be the exact same object that was saved.
         // Using the 2nd way, this will return an array with 1 item. So take the 0th element, ie data[0]
         this.employee = data; // data[0]
      });
    }
  );
}
```

Note: Always maintain Types to get the benefits of TypeScript.

Comment: ,This is working only for the first click if I click update button for 2nd records it was still showing the first one.any clue

Comment: You will need to provide some more code, to be able to know where the mistake is. A wild guess would be for you to take a look at where you are calling the getEmployeeByID(). If you note, I have moved it inside the params.subscribe() call whereas your original call had it outside.

Comment: sorry I did the mistake. It is working now. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue here is you're assuming `this.id` is assigned a value by the time you call `this.employeeService.getEmployeeById(this.id)`. But `this.id` is assgined asynchronously. Though it might be assigned sometimes correctly, it can't be guaranteed to be everytime. In this case you could use one of RxJS higher order mapping operators like `switchMap`.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.activeRoute.params.pipe(
    switchMap(data => {
      this.id = data['id'];
      console.log('id::'+this.id);
      return this.employeeService.getEmployeeById(this.id);
    })
  ).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.employee = data.map((e) => ({
        firstName:e.payload.doc.data()['firstName'],
        lastName: e.payload.doc.data()['lastName']
      }))
      console.log(this.employee);
    }
  );
}
```

This probably won't solve your issue. For that to work you need to make sure the `data` in the subscription is an array. If not, you can't invoke `map` function on it.

Comment: in the fire base db record corresponding to that id is storing as key/value pairs and I just want to retrieve those records. How to pass it as an array from my service call? Any idea will be helpfull.

Comment: @stumbler: You're doing a `console.log(data)` inside the subscription. Please show it's output to get a clear picture of your data structure.

Comment: sure. Edited .Please check

Comment: It seems the response is an object and it does not contain the `doc` property you're referring to. You need to check again how to access the key/value pair that you mentioned.

Comment: actually here I am not queried for against the document Id. I have queried against employee id. Is the service call right?Do you have any idea?